# behat symfony2 facebook api test

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, behat, mink

im using behat to test my symfony2 projects specifically a test project i have to be a sandbox for my [bundles](https://github.com/bitgandtter/bundles).

One of the bundles to test is my [FacebookBundle](https://github.com/bitgandtter/FacebookBundle) that integrate facebook api into symfony2 projects. This bundle provide several twig extensions. In the authenticate url of the bundles project i use one of this twig extensions to render the facebook login url but when i test it with behat i get this error:

```
 An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (&quot;Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php line 1187&quot;) in TestBundle:Default:auth.html.twig at line 13.
```

But i dont see any reason why this is happening, the project work just fine but testing with behat faild.

Any help, thanks

## EDIT

Extrange im testing this project on travis and there all behat test pass, see travis: travis-ci.org/bitgandtter/bundles/jobs/37200512

## EDIT2

It seams only happend with symfony2 driver for mink, i chage to goutte and work just fine, i review the code and symfony2 driver extend from mink-browse-kit driver, it will be nice to have some configuration options over it, i will keep digging to find the issue

Comment: The Facebook API is using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, which doesn't exist on the CLI. I believe you can specify one in `server_parameters` for testing purposes.

Comment: any reference to server_parameters configuration on symfony projects? or any other project

Comment: https://github.com/alistairstead/BehatMage/blob/master/behat.yml.dist has an example that may help